# Google Project Tango, taking pictures while tracking motion

Tags: google-project-tango

I'd like to use the Google Tango motion tracking while taking pictures. The Tango service precludes using the android camera API. From what I can tell, it's not possible to control the camera (ISO, exposure, white balance) or take still shots while the Tango service is running. True?

The online java API documents show that TangoConfig has a constant called `KEY_BOOLEAN_COLORMODEAUTO`, but the `TangoConfig` class declaration in the `TangoSDK_Leibnitz.jar` does not have it. Is there a way to control the camera? If the java API does not support this, does the C API?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the OnFrameAvailable is what you want -  it returns a regular image stream from the color or fisheye camera via callbacks.  That said, it was busted several releases ago, and for the latest release (Leibnitz) there seems to be some confusion over format, and some concern over stability.  DO NOT try and acquire the camera yourself, or Tango looses access to it

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell, you have access in C API (and latest Leibniz release) to disabling auto camera config and then set ISO params (i tried yesterday), and the cloud acquisition AND color frame acquistion is running fine. But this seems to be for Color Cam only ( not explicitly said, but FishEye seems not tunable like this).

Extract of comment from tango_client_api. h :

"
The supported configuration parameters that can be set are:

```
///
/// <table>
/// <tr><td class="indexkey">boolean config_color_mode_auto</td><td
/// class="indexvalue">
/// Use auto-exposure/auto-whitebalance with the color camera.  Defaults to
/// true, and
/// if true, the values for config_color_iso and config_color_exp are ignored.
/// </td></tr>
///
/// <tr><td class="indexkey">int32 config_color_iso</td><td
/// class="indexvalue">ISO value for the color camera.
///         One of 100, 200, 400 or 800.  Default is 100.  Only applied if
///         config_color_mode_auto is set to false.</td></tr>
///
/// <tr><td class="indexkey">int32 config_color_exp</td><td class="indexvalue">
///         Exposure value for the color camera, in nanoseconds.  Default is
///         11100000 (11.1 ms).  Valid from 0 to 30000000.  Only applied if
///         config_color_mode_auto is set to false.</td></tr>
```

...
"